# Find a specific tag with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I can traverse generic tags easily with BS, but I don't know how to find specific tags. For example, how can I find all occurances of `<div style="width=300px;">`? Is this possible with BS?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The following should work

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlstring)
soup.findAll('div', style="width=300px;")
```

There are couple of ways to search for tags.

- https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-the-tree

For more text to understand and use it

- http://lxml.de/elementsoup.html

Answer (score 15):

with bs4 things have changed a little. so the code should look like this

`soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlstring,'lxml')
soup.find_all('div', {'style':"width=300px;"})`