# BeautifulSoup: Find table by style

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Is it possible to find a specific table with unique style?

Say, given the following html:

```
<table border="1" style="background-color:White;font-size:10pt;border-collapse:collapse;">
```

How can I use BS to find that table?

Thanks

Comment: have a look into: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945750/find-a-specific-tag-with-beautifulsoup

Comment: you wish to fetch a table with unique style?

Answer (score 18):

Try it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
bs = BeautifulSoup(htmlcontent)
bs.find_all('table', attrs={'border': '1' ,'style':'background-color:White;font-size:10pt;border-collapse:collapse;'})
```

Check [this link](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) for more details.

Comment: Missing a curly bracket.

Comment: Find all WITHOUT style, is that possible?

Comment: @CodeGuru what about leaving `attrs` empty?

Comment: thanks, this really helped. I used the following to append to an array(list): allstateswithparks = []

for tag in soup.find_all('td', attrs={'style': 'text-align: center; width: 140px;'}):
    allstateswithparks.append(tag.get_text())

Answer (score 4):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get("https://www.lipsum.com/")
soup =   BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")
print(soup.find_all('div',style=lambda value: value and 'text-align:justify' in value))
```

Note: important use attrs for class !!!

Comment: You should add in value in the end. 

print(soup.find_all('div',style=lambda value: value and 'text-align:justify' in value))