# How do I web scrape an element using its style definitions like padding, font-size etc. in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to extract a div using its style property `padding-left: 16px`, something like shown in the following Python code. But apparently it doesn't work. I know how to extract an element using its class, id or tags. Is there a way to do the same using style property?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

f = open("C:\Users\admin\Documents\GitHub\RedditCrawler\new.html");
soup = BeautifulSoup(f);
f.close();

hr2 = soup.find('div', style={"padding-left":"16px"});

print(hr2);
```

Following is the div I'm trying to extract from my html file:

```
<html>
<div style="padding-left:16px;">This is the deal</div>
</html>
```

Comment: one of these should work https://stackoverflow.com/a/23584775/1289093  https://stackoverflow.com/a/35140202/1289093

Comment: @yolabingo Thank You for the quick reply. The first link worked for me. It is strange though that I couldn't find the already answered similar question even though I had been searching here for quite a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSS selector to get the div element.

> soup.select_one('div[style="padding-left:16px;"]')

**Code**:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html='''<html>
<div style="padding-left:16px;">This is the deal</div>
</html>'''
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
#To get the element
print(soup.select_one('div[style="padding-left:16px;"]'))
#To get the text
print(soup.select_one('div[style="padding-left:16px;"]').text)
#To get the style value
print(soup.select_one('div[style="padding-left:16px;"]')['style'])
```

**Output**:

```
<div style="padding-left:16px;">This is the deal</div>
This is the deal
padding-left:16px;
```