# Formatting an HTML tag

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, format

I have an HTML page that looks like this:

```
<html>
   <head>
     <title>TEST</title>
   </head>
   <body>
     <p>Testing</p>
     <iframe src="{}" width="500" height="500"></iframe>
   </body>
</html>
```

I need to format the `<iframe src="{}` part with a website link, for example: `<iframe src="https://google.com"`.

My question is, how can I format a tag in an HTML string using python built-in libraries (or external)? Here is my attempt:

```
retval = ""
for item in HTML_page.readlines():
    if "<iframe src" in item:
        item = item.format(LINK)
        retval += item 
    else:
        retval += item
    return retval
```

This works, but it isn't very pretty. Is there a way I can do this more python like?

Comment: so you basically want to dynamically change the src of  an iframe ?

Comment: @RohitasBehera yes, I didn't know the wording to use, sorry. But that is basically what I want.

Comment: This might be the one you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945750/find-a-specific-tag-with-beautifulsoup

Comment: Also, can you post your attempt? We could help you with it

Comment: @yklsga I'm still working on it. I posted an example of my attempt

Comment: @Gyzo. `html = open('page.html').read().format(LINK)`.

Comment: did you try replace function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using beautifulsoup, you can do it as

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'insert your url here'

with open('file.html','r') as f:
    text = f.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(text,'html.parser')

soup.body.iframe['src'] = url

with open('file.html','w') as f:
    f.write(str(soup))
```

Without using any third party libraries, since you already got it. I removed a few statements and modified the code

```
retval = ""
HTML_page = open('file.html','r')
LINK = 'google.com'

for item in HTML_page.readlines():
    if "<iframe src" in item:
        item = item.format(LINK)
    retval += item

HTML_page.close()
print(retval)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the HTML code looks like this:

```
<html>
   <head>
     <title>TEST</title>
   </head>
   <body>
     <p>Foo</p>
     <iframe src="{}" width="500" height="500"></iframe>
     <p>Bar</p>
     <iframe src="{}" width="500" height="500"></iframe>
   </body>
</html>
```

Then you can simply use `str.format` on all of links:

```
URLS = (
    "https://www.example.com/",
    "https://www.example.com/"
)

html_code = """<html>
   <head>
     <title>TEST</title>
   </head>
   <body>
     <p>Foo</p>
     <iframe src="{}" width="500" height="500"></iframe>
     <p>Bar</p>
     <iframe src="{}" width="500" height="500"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
"""
html_code = html_code.format(*URLS)
```

Comment: It's being read from a HTML file, and that's what I'm doing in my example.