# How to pass in the source HTML code into BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

I want to web scrape results from a search on a website. The search terms appear in the URL so I just import urllib.request and do

```
source = urllib.request.urlopen('https://....').read()
```

then I pass that into the BeautifulSoup constructor

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(source)
```

I want to find_all('div') the div tags. However, it looks like you can only pass in html code into the BeautifulSoup constructor. It seems that the `urllib.request.urlopen('https://...').read()` returns the page source, not the inspect elements. How do I pass in the inspect elements into the BeautifulSoup constructor?

Comment: _However, it looks like you can only pass in html code into the BeautifulSoup constructor._ Yes, since BeautifulSoup is an HTML parser, that is to be expected. _However, it looks like you can only pass in html code into the BeautifulSoup constructor._ What do you mean by _inspect elements_ ? Please clarify your question, see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Why didn't you read the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) or a decent [tutorial](https://codeburst.io/web-scraping-101-with-python-beautiful-soup-bb617be1f486) before starting?

Comment: When you right click a page, there's options to view page source and to inspect. The HTML that you see when you inspect is what I'm interested in.

Comment: @Pedro Lobito Because the documentation didn't really specify the difference between the kinds of HTML code to pass into BeautifulSoup. The tutorial link is nice but passing requests.get(url).content to BeautifulSoup must be giving me issues because there is a plethora of div tags for my url but find_all('div') gives me nothing. When I do requests.get(url).content, it displays a bunch of javascript code. I just want the plain HTML just like what you see when you inspect a page.

Answer (score 0):

The BeautifulSoup constructor function takes in two string arguments:

The HTML string to be parsed.
Optionally, the name of a parser.

from:
http://www.compjour.org/warmups/govt-text-releases/intro-to-bs4-lxml-parsing-wh-press-briefings/

You can't pass find values to the constructor just use findAll mentioned in my previous answer.

[Find a specific tag with BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945750/find-a-specific-tag-with-beautifulsoup)

Edit: Reading from your comments here is what I think you're looking for:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_doc = urllib.request.urlopen('https://....').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

print(soup.prettify())
```

Check out: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/