# How to find specific header in a div when web scraping using Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm currently trying to scape the headers within a div, shown in the following screenshot:

[I am trying to find the text highlighted in light blue from the div class in green, but instead my code (below) print the code boxed in pink.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDd8W.png)

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1cyh.png)

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: The headers do not contain any tags or class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find a specific tag with BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945750/find-a-specific-tag-with-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is just the club name and & amount for each separate club, then you need to `.findAll()` the `<h3>` tags, rather than requesting the content of a specific box. The `<h3>` tags contain the information you want, and `.findAll()` pulls them out as a list.

Here's a minimal example:

```py
# Import statements

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Get the page

page = requests.get("https://talksport.com/football/572055/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content)

# Find all the H3 tags and store them in a list

clubs = soup.findAll("h3")

# Print out the text of each heading
# I've picked the list indexes to ignore the irrelevant H3 tags. I could 
# also have filtered by the text itself, but for a single page, this works.

for club in clubs[17:-2]:
    print(club.text)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! For anyone who has had this issue and has used this answer, to avoid the warning message, replace "soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content)" with "soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content)"

Comment: I can't see the difference.